# change package layout with file xml in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i'm using magento 1.9.2
in the admin page i config package for my frontend is: rwd
Now i'm building up a module called: mycustom

when the customer go to mydomain.com/mycustom the package name is "mypackage" not rwd package
how to make it
thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do it. The quick and ugly way is to check the current customer's group and then set the theme programatically:

```
Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')
    ->setPackageName('your_package')
    ->setTheme('your_theme');
```

You can see the following article to more understanding 
[Magento change theme programmatically](https://santoshyadavcse.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/magento-channge-them/)